# How do you publish an app that runs on an external dataset to shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a function, `predictAll()`, that takes an english phrase as the input and returns the next most likely word. I have created a shiny app which references the function and runs fine locally. In the application, the user enters the phrase and the app returns the next recommended word.

My question is, how can I publish the application to ShinyApps? The `predictAll` function is based off a large text document, stored locally, and it takes about 10 mins to run the program that generates it. Is it possible for the function to work on ShinyApps without uploading the original data set and all the code that comes with it?

Comment: What is the problem with uploading the file and not touching it ever again? Is the file too big? Does it changes often? If it changes often but it is not too big, you can host it in an accessible place like github and read the file from there

Comment: you have to build the model first then save it as a file that you then load in shiny to make the prediction. Control the size of the file so that it fits in shinyapps and loads quickly enough. Good luck for the capstone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two (well, three) possibilities:

1) If your data/app is such that you can pre-process or subset your data before uploading the app, do what HubertL suggested in the comment and upload only the data you need to run the app to shinyapps.io. Run what needs to be done once locally, export the results, and upload the results and the code that depends on user interaction to your shiny app.

2) If you need to access a larger dataset than you can upload to shinyapps.io, you can host it remotely and load it in via URL. If reading plain text or CSV data, `readLines('your_data_url')` or `read.csv('your_data_url')` should do the trick. For JSON or XML data, see the `jsonlite` or `XML` packages.

3) If the place you will host the data externally happens to be a (virtual private) server, you can install Shiny Server on it and do everything there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I used the `save()` function to export my n-gram data frame objects to an .RDATA file. I also updated my server.r file so it would load the objects from the file. I then uploaded all 3 files (server.r, ui.r, ngrams.RDATA) to shinyapps, which worked beautifully.

Comment: See also: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/07/persistent-data-storage-in-shiny-apps/